# Why is <*> an infix function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Perhaps this is not the right place to ask and presumably this question is too 'meta', but is there any reason the `<*>` (and analogously `<$>`) function is infix? To my understanding and my knowledge (thus far) of Haskell it does the same as `fmap`.

So, why is `fmap` not infix but its Applicative and Functor variant are?

Comment: Someone or other wrote about `<$>`, `<*>`, and `=<<` all being variations on function application. So it's helpful to give them all vaguely similar syntax. As Cale Gibbard (I think) said, it's unfortunate that `$` is right associative while all the other sorts of application are left associative.

Comment: Note that `<*>` isn't the same as fmap: rather, `<$>` is actually a synonym for fmap, and `<*>` is something that is *a lot like fmap*, but a bit different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it's mostly motivated by this idiom:

```
f <$> x <*> y <*> z
```

Spelled with prefix functions it's a lot less pretty, and you need to know how many applications there are just to start typing:

```
ap (ap (fmap f x) y) z
```

Comment: Though you could of course still write ``f `fmap` x `ap` y `ap` z``.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sure. And if you're going to be doing that all the time, you might as well choose function names that can be used infix.

Comment: It's also worth mention that `<*>` has a stronger specification than `ap`, as it works on all Applicatives, and therefore all Monads, but `ap` only works on Monads.